# Only show a certain count of textboxes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I'm trying to make several TextBoxes visible and invisible, depending on the number in another textbox. In Fact I have 14(TextBox1, TextBox2, ...), this is my code so far:

```
Dim s As Integer = 0

While s > 14
   s += 1
   Dim txtBox As String = "TextBox" & CStr(s)
   CObj(txtBox).Visible = False
End While




If txtBoxHowmany.Text = "" Then

   Else
      Dim s As Integer = 0

      While s > txtBoxHowmany.Text
            s += 1
            Dim txtBox As String = "TextBox" & CStr(s)
            CObj(txtBox).Visible = True
      End While
End If
```

Comment: From looking at that, the first while loop will not execute, 0 is less than 14 so the condition `s > 14` will not be true when you get to the while loop. You also can't get a text box from turning the string name to an object. I'd advise using `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file to light up other issues. I'll attempt to answer this but would need more information to make the answer work properly.

Comment: If you make an array of references to the textboxes, like `Dim tbs = {Textbox1, Textbox2, Textbox3, Textbox4, Textbox5, Textbox6, Textbox7, Textbox8, Textbox9, Textbox10, Textbox11, Textbox12, Textbox13, Textbox14}` then you can refer to them numerically like `tbs(s).Visible = True` - just remember that arrays start at an index of 0, not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a list of text boxes and filled it in form Load. You can use this list in any method in your form.

In the Button.Click I used `.TryParse` to check the contents of `TextBox7`. I added a number range to the test with AndAlso's. AndAlso short circuits the `If` so that the following conditions will not be checked if the previous condition is False.

Next we use the `.Take` extension Function to get the text boxes we want to alter. A `For Each` loop actual changes the `.Visible` state.

```
Private TBoxes As New List(Of TextBox)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TBoxes.AddRange({TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5, TextBox6})
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim NumVisible As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox7.Text, NumVisible) AndAlso NumVisible > 0 AndAlso NumVisible < 15 Then
        Dim VisibleBoxes = TBoxes.Take(NumVisible)
        For Each tb In VisibleBoxes
            tb.Visible = True
        Next
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: but now I'm encountering a new, weird problem: Every time I type a single letter in any of the 14 TextBoxes, the selection switches to the button

Comment: Tested typing into the boxes after they are displayed and it behaves normally. Nothing should be setting focus back to the button. Set up a `TextChanged` event handler and some dummy code where you can set a break point for the text box you are attempting to type in  and maybe something will show up.

Answer (score 0):

Design tip: use a [spinner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/numericupdown-control-overview-windows-forms) instead of a textbox.
Then you define the `Minimum` and `Maximum` values, while `Value` represents the currently-selected value. That makes the code more robust against incorrect input.

So the code could look like this:

```
dim s as integer = Me.spinner.Value
For i as Integer = 1 to s
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & s.ToString).Visible = True
next
```

If value 5 is selected, then TextBox1 through TextBox5 become visible and you can continue with the rest and hide them as required.

Or a slightly more advanced example:

```
dim s as integer = me.spinner.Value

For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls
    Dim i as integer = 1
    If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
        If ctl.Name.StartsWith("TextBox") Then
            If ctl.Name = ("TextBox" & i.ToString()) ' eg TextBox1, TextBox5...
                If i <= s Then ' counter <= value of spinner
                    ctl.Visible= True
                Else
                    ctl.Visible= False
                End If
            End If
            i += 1
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Here we loop on the form's child controls, look for those of Textbox type. `i` is an internal counter that is incremented at each occurrence of a TextBox control which name starts with 'TextBox'. If the control name starts with TextBox, and the rest of the string is a number <= spinner value, we set the Visible property to True. Otherwise, Visible is set to False.

So if the spinner value is 5, controls TextBox1 through TextBox5 should become visible, while the rest are to be hidden. The advantage to this approach is that the number of textboxes can be variable.

Disclaimer: untested code.

---

Update 09 March 2020

Here is a revised version that relies on a LINQ query to fetch a **sorted** list of textboxes in the form, assuming your controls are always named in the same pattern ie textbox1 through 14.

In theory this code could do the trick but it will not sort like I want ie textbox1 will be followed by textbox11, 12, 13, 14 and then textbox2.

```
Dim textboxes= From txt In Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)() _
   Where txt.Name.StartsWith("TextBox") _
   Order By txt.Name ' 1, 2, 14...
```

So I have tweaked the expression a little bit. I am assigning a variable textbox_number from LINQ to extract the number of the textbox:

```
Dim textboxes = From txt In Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)() _
          Let textbox_number = Convert.ToInt32(txt.Name.Substring(7, txt.Name.Length - 7)) _
           Where txt.Name.StartsWith("TextBox") _
           Order By textbox_number ' 1, 2, 14...
```

This function is for demonstration purposes and should be improved to be made safer. It will work for your purpose though. By doing this trick I can perform a **numeric sort** so that that the controls are listed in the right order.
So if you select 5 in the spinner then controls 1 through 5 are made visible and the rest are hidden.

I have attached a screenshot. Note that I put all the textboxes in a [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=netframework-4.8) to improve presentation.
Probably, your controls are placed directly  in the form and not in a container, then simply replace Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls with Me.Controls.

```
Public Class frmtextboxes

    Private Sub butShow_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles butShow.Click
        Dim s As Integer = Me.spinner.Value ' number of textboxes to show

        ' LINQ query: get list of textboxes sorted by number
        Dim textboxes = From txt In Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)() _
                  Let textbox_number = Convert.ToInt32(txt.Name.Substring(7, txt.Name.Length - 7)) _
                   Where txt.Name.StartsWith("TextBox") _
                   Order By textbox_number ' 1, 2, 14...

        For Each ctl In textboxes
            Console.WriteLine("TextBox found, name: " & ctl.txt.Name & "=> " & ctl.textbox_number)
            If ctl.textbox_number <= s Then
                Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls(ctl.txt.Name).Visible = True ' make control visible
            Else
                Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls(ctl.txt.Name).Visible = False ' hide control
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]